# Displaying a 3D function without a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have a 3D function $z=\dfrac{x}{y}$, and I have no access to a function grapher, but I still need to display this function in a comprehensible way. I thought of a table, but even with a domain of $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\in(-2,2)\right\}$, the table has 25 rows. That is to say, a lot of rows, and so little space to do so.

## Question

What should I do, in my predicament? *How can I display a 3D function **without** a graph?*

My main endeavor is to calculate limits concerning this graph, whilst conveying this information to the reader.

### Edit

I cannot stress the fact enough that I have no access to graphing functions. If it helps, think that I'm typing this up in plaintext, without graphics of any kind.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but why don't you use level sets?

Comment: @JessicaK I am not acquainted with 'level sets'; what are they?

Comment: Fix $z$ to be a constant, and then graph $c = x/y$. For each value of $c$ you will visually get a slice of your surface. Vary $c$ to get an idea of what the entire image looks like. e.g. $z=x^{2} + y^{2}$ gives you a collection of circles centered at the origin with increasing radii representing slices of a paraboloid.

Comment: This day, even typing `z = x/y` into google will return you a plot. Of course, the proper way to get a graph online is using [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com). You can generate a graph there using the command  `plot z = x/y`.

Comment: @JessicaK That certainly is insightful, however; as you stated, it isn't quite what I want; it is cumbersome, as I see it (practically being a table itself).

Comment: An idea similar to level sets would be to use a [heat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map)

Comment: @achillehui True enough, but I was looking for an alternative to graphing to display a 3D function.

Comment: displaying a 3D function on what media? On your own web page or printed material or blackboard?

Comment: @achillehui I'm attempting to have this printed in a document I'm working on.

Comment: If you are unwilling to use a table or insert an image, I can't see any other option besides describing the surface in words.